# Increment number while getting object from fauna db?

Tags: faunadb

I am currently getting an object from my fauna database collection with an Index like so:

```
Get(
    Match(
        Index("byURL"),
        "rv49z1"
    )
)
```

I would also like to be able to increment a number variable (`clicks`) in the document I fetch each time I fetch it, ideally in one command.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Let(
  { o: Get(...) },
  Update(
    Select("ref", Var("o")),
    {
       data: {
         clicks: Add(1, Select(["data", "clicks"], Var("o")))
       }
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want the document back before the update:

```
Let(
  {
    doc:Get(Match('byURL','rv49z1')),
    ref:Select(['ref'],Var('doc')),
    upd: Update(Var('ref'),{data:{clicks:Add(1,Select(['data','clicks'],Var('doc')))}})},
  {
    doc:Var('doc'),
    upd:Var('upd')
  }
)
```

But such operation is a read/delete/write operation at the storage engine level.
If your documents are big and you do that many times, I'd suggest moving the counter somewhere else.

Luigi